# EF Reference gets lost when Web API returns IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, lazy-loading, iqueryable

I have been looking for quite some time now on this problem.

Here's the deal.
I'm building a website that calls to a Web API to get its data. My Web API uses a library, working with repository pattern. My database model (EF Model-first) was build in the library. In that model I have a base class Pass. Then I have two derived classes, CustomerCard : Pass and Voucher : Pass. [My model from EF Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jug79.png)

I have a method to get all the CustomerCards.

```
public IQueryable<CustomerCard> GetAllPasses() {
        IList<CustomerCard> allCards = new List<CustomerCard>();

        var c_cards = context.Passes;
        foreach (var c_card in c_cards) {
            if (c_card is CustomerCard) {
                allCards.Add((CustomerCard)c_card);
            }
        }
        return allCards.AsQueryable<CustomerCard>();
    }
```

In my ApiController, I use this method to get the passes and return them to the website, like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<CustomerCard> GetAllPasses(string version) {
        return passRepo.GetAllPasses().AsQueryable();
    }
```

My Web API returns JSON format. This is my config to preserve referencing and stuff:

```
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

I'm using IQueryable because I want to be able to page the data on my website. The api method is available at '/api/v1/passes/all'.

Here's the strange part. To test my paging, I call 1 pass per page.
For my first Pass, it works fine. But when I go to my second page, he also gets the correct pass, but the reference to User is gone.

As you can see in [my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jug79.png), the CustomerCard class has a property User. This indicates who owns the customer card.

So this call loads the user from the pass: 'api/v1/passes/all?$top=1'
but when I call to this one, the user instance is *NULL*: 'api/v1/passes/all?$top=1&$skip=1'.

However, when I call to 'api/v1/passes/all?$top=2', the User for the second pass IS loaded.
So this is where my mind get's blown! I don't get it? Why doesn't the user-reference comes along with the second one? Could it have something to do with the Lazy loading feature of the EF?

EDIT
When I use the extension method Include on context.passes, an error is thrown:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'LCS_Model.Pass'
>   does not declare a navigation property with the name 'User'.

This is because Passes as a dbset, contains CustomerCard as well as Voucher. Is there a way I can tell my context to expect or convert it to a CustomerCard?

Can someone please help me. If you don't understand my question, ask away!

Thanks allready!

**EDIT 2**

The method on my API controller is now

```
[HttpGet]
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<CustomerCard> GetAllPasses(string version) {
     return context.Passes.Include("User").OfType<CustomerCard>();
}
```

This gives me my correct items. I have 2 customer cards in my db. Both are from the same user. My API has the user still loaded. The moment my website receives the response, the User property becomes null. My guess is that it's because it is still referencing to the same user from the first element of the array. Is that possible? And if yes, how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: could you add the controller code for Method "all"?

Comment: The second code block is the controller code. the route 'api/{version}/passes/all' routes to action = "GetAllPasses".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to make sure any related records are included when you do your query.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857.aspx) for some examples.  Secondly... I fail to understand why you are doing all that work with the for loop... That's a lot of absolutely needless and wasted work for the server to do if you want to do any paging.  I'm thinking, besides any other filters you might want to apply, your GetAllPasses should look something like this.

```
public IQueryable<CustomerCard> GetAllPasses() {
    return context.Passes.Include(r => r.User);
}
```

Edit (2): I need to read better.  I have to confess, I'm not familiar with type inheritance in EF.  I found some things that might work here:  [table per hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx), [table per concrete type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293), and see also also [MSDN Queryable.OfType<TResult>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857.aspx).  This is a guess, but let's try:

```
public IQueryable<CustomerCard> GetAllPasses() {
    return context.Passes.OfType<CustomerCard>().Include(r => r.User);
}
```

Comment: That was my initial solution as well. The problem is that my EF Model created only one dbset. The Users-property is only available for the child type CustomerCard (a separate table generated in my db [dbo].[Passes_CustomerCard]. So when I want to use your suggested method with Include, I get the error saying that User is not a property. That's my biggest problem. Can I tell my context that it needs to take it from CustomerCard or something?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it first thing in the morning! I'll let you know

Comment: The OfType<CustomerCard>() was a better way than my initial for-loop. So thanks for that. But I can't seem to use the Include(r => r.User) method after it. Include is an extension only for DbSet. Also, Include only takes a string as a path. But that's not the problem. My current code is return context.Passes.Include("User").OfType<CustomerCard>(); It gives me my passes with the right type, but still no user in the second one. It's a strange issue. Thanks though for the answer

Comment: Did you ever put the `Include` after `OfType`? Just curious.

Comment: Yes, when I put the Include after OfType, I can include the child properties. I've got it working now. Everytime I used my context, I turned of ProxyCreationEnabled (set it to False). Then in my library I added the appropriate include statements. Now I don't have a problem anymore. Thanks for your help!